# how to avoid problems with modules when transforming code into executable - Python

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-module

I have a project that is working perfectly in `.py` format, but when I make it executable using pyinstaller, I have problems if the module I created and is being used in the code is not in the same folder. So, how could I create an executable of my code, without having to put the module I created in the same folder as the executable, since if it was for a client, he wouldn't have the module on the system?

the module is called `numbers` and this function is one of those that checks the values received in the user's input

```
import numbers
def check_price(values):

        number_filter = numbers.parseNumber(values['price_input'])

        if number_filter == None:
            sg.popup_error('Value Error', 'Input a number')
            raise ValueError('the value is not a number')
```

Comment: Can you give a [mre] of the layout of your project?

Comment: @RandomDavis i'll edit my question  and put it

Comment: `__init__.py`?  Maybe give an outline of the folder structure of the module you want to import and files? try adding __init__.py to the folder with the code you want to import.

Comment: @Chinny84 when i created the module folder, vs code created the `__init__` automatically, but it is empty. should i add something?

Comment: it depends - but `__init__.py` basically helps python locate imports - take a look at this https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html and then come back if there is an error.

Comment: @Chinny84 unfortunately I didn't find anything that helped me in the documentation

Comment: Ok - print out the directory structure from root to all the files you want to import.

Comment: there is no problem in the directory, what I'm trying if there is any way to send the executable to someone, without having to send the module along, or whenever I use a module in a code, will I have to send it to the user along with the executable?

Comment: In short no - https://realpython.com/pyinstaller-python/. Have  a look at this.